# How do I select the minimum and maximum values for a horizontal lollipop plot/dumbbell chart?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a dumbbell chart but I am getting too many minimum and maximum values for each category type. I want to display only one skyblue dot (the minimum price) and one green dot (the maximum price) per area.

This is what the chart looks like so far:

[My dumbbell chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAXsV.png)

Here is my DataFrame:

[The DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnCzc.png)

Here is a link to the full dataset:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpI6PlO8ox2vKfM4aGmEUexCPPWa59S_

And here is my code so far:

```
   import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    db = df[['minPrice','maxPrice', 'neighbourhood_hosts']]
    ordered_db = db.sort_values(by='minPrice')
    my_range=db['neighbourhood_hosts']

    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=ordered_db['minPrice'], xmax=ordered_db['maxPrice'], color='grey', alpha=0.4)
    plt.scatter(ordered_db['minPrice'], my_range, color='skyblue', alpha=1, label='minimum price')
    plt.scatter(ordered_db['maxPrice'], my_range, color='green', alpha=0.4 , label='maximum price')
    plt.legend()


    plt.title("Comparison of the minimum and maximum prices")
    plt.xlabel('Value range')
    plt.ylabel('Area')
```

How can I format my code so that I only have one minimum and one maximum value for each area?

Comment: please give us the entire dataframe. thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've just added a link to the data now

Comment: Thanks. I see your data now. I see that you are basically plotting every points on the data in a scatter graph. If you want only the min and max per area, then create a set of area and min, max per area. You can create min_ordered_db will have have only min values per area and max_ordered_db with max values. then use them to plot in your scatter graph. Let me know if you need help on this.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm trying to figure out how to make that new DataFrame now. If I'm still stuck I'll ask you on here. I really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid I'm still struggling here. I was only able to create the type of table I need in Excel, and am struggling to re-create it with Pandas. I've seen what the graph is supposed to look like, but I also want the categories to be ordered by variance from largest to smallest. Can you help with this?

Comment: I also added a sorting based on variance of minPrice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per conversation, here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('dumbbell data.csv')
db = df[['minPrice','maxPrice', 'neighbourhood_hosts']]
#create max and min price based on area name
max_price = db.groupby(['neighbourhood_hosts'])['maxPrice'].max().reset_index()
min_price = db.groupby(['neighbourhood_hosts'])['minPrice'].min().reset_index()
var_price = pd.DataFrame()
var_price['range'] = max_price.maxPrice-min_price.minPrice
var_price['neighbourhood_hosts'] = min_price['neighbourhood_hosts']
var_price = var_price.sort_values(by='range')

#sort max and min price according to variance
max_price = max_price.reindex(var_price.index)
min_price = min_price.reindex(var_price.index)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.hlines(y=min_price['neighbourhood_hosts'], xmin=min_price['minPrice'], xmax=max_price['maxPrice'], color='grey', alpha=0.4)
plt.scatter(min_price['minPrice'], min_price['neighbourhood_hosts'], color='skyblue', alpha=1, label='minimum price')
plt.scatter(max_price['maxPrice'], max_price['neighbourhood_hosts'], color='green', alpha=0.4 , label='maximum price')
plt.legend()


plt.title("Comparison of the minimum and maximum prices")
plt.xlabel('Value range')
plt.ylabel('Area')
```

[image]

Comment: There is just one thing though, shouldn't Canonbury be third in this plot inplace of Chelsea, and Wimbledon after that? I was hoping to have these dumbbells in order from largest to smallest

Comment: print(var_price) and you will see the variance of Chelsea vs Canonbury. Chelsea has variance of 235 while Canonbury is 106.  Do you mean range? Range is difference between max and min while variance is amount of scattered data from the mean

Comment: I mean range. I'm sorry, I've got the terms confused.  How do I sort this list by range rather than variance?

Comment: I hope to be half as good as you are at this some day! Thank you so much for your help. I'm truly grateful.